# 2 divs on same line?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get 2 divs on the same line, but alligned differently. Here is a pic of what I have right now and what I want:

[pic removed by poster]

and here is the code I've got:

```
<div class="newsdiv">
    <div class="picdiv" style="background-image: url('[...]');"></div>
    <div class="titlediv">
        <a href="#"><font size="4">', $row['title'], '</font></a>
    </div>
    <div class="textdiv">
        <font size="1">This is some dummy text</font>
    </div>
    <div class="linksdiv">
        <a href="#">[Read More...]</a>
        <div class="statsdiv">
            <a href="#">Views: 0 , Comments: 0</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the stylesheet:

```
.newsdiv{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 126px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.picdiv{
    width: 220px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 382px 120px;
    float: left;
}
.titlediv{
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.textdiv{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 8px;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
.linksdiv{
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
}
.statsdiv{
    font-size: 7pt;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Wow! Amazing opportunity for answering with "add `float: right`"...

Comment: yes but that's the wrong answer ;)

Comment: @Chris check my comment below the answer!

Comment: Yes I know that @Chris,  that's why I didn't answer... :D  I already figured it out from the images you posted.

Comment: Why dont you use `position` instead of `float`.

Comment: I [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012053/1369473) without the use of float.  Probably much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `position: absolute;` on your `.statsdiv` and `position:relative;` on `.linksdiv` to achieve what you want.  I guess using `float` will be too much for this.

**Updated CSS(modified classes only):**

```
.linksdiv{
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;  /*added*/
}
.statsdiv{
    font-size: 7pt;
    /* text-align: right;  not required */
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute; /*added*/
    right: -0.5%;       /*added*/
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CGt2q/)**

Comment: `Float` will not be too much than using `positioned` elements! setting up a **negative** margins is not a good idea ever!

Answer (score 3):

You need `float` here

```
.statsdiv {
  font-size: 7pt;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  float: right; /* Add this */
}
```

May be there will be more cleaner solution but you can try this for now

```
.linksdiv > a{
    margin-left:12%;
}
```

### [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yTHt/2/)

Comment: Yeah i tried this. Not exactly what I want:
http://i.imgur.com/vi7m6e4.png
The [Read More] is centered on the main wrapper, not centered with the title.

Comment: Very bad... there has to be a better solution than `.linksdiv > a{margin-left:12%;}`...

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Let's wait for that!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak, yes that worked! Anyway to fix it so that the text on the right doesn't cut?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr, yes I agree this isn't the "cleanest" solution, but so far the only that works :)

Comment: @Chris It will not cut as i'm targeting the immediate descendant in the `.linksdiv` class :)

Comment: yeah my browser was being funny. Update your reply and I'll mark it as best answer. thanks!

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012053/1369473),  it doesn't use float or margins.  The right margin I used on child div is to keep the stats from sticking to border.  I just used `position` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this working css. Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7PX/1/)

```
.statsdiv {
font-size: 7pt;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
height: 10px;
float: right;/*added*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.statsdiv` css

```
float:right;
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cc68d/

Edit :- Although this works, as pointed out by you , it does not align Read More[..] in center. Actually the issue is with the design part. I will not go into details.  You can correct this by adding `style="padding-left:100px;"` to your ReadMore[..] `<a>` tag attribute.

as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/cc68d/1/

Comment: The [read more] isnt centered with the rest of the text - just centered with the main wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Add a third div with a width of how ever wide you need it with no content between  them -  a place holder div ...remember to float right , text align and a margin as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your total css code, You need float on the class `.statsdiv`

Your total modified code is:

```
.newsdiv{
overflow: hidden;
height: 126px;
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.picdiv{
width: 220px;
height: 110px;
border: 1px solid #444;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 382px 120px;
float: left;
}
.titlediv{
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
.textdiv{
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 8px;
height: 70px;
text-align: center;
}
.linksdiv{
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-align: center;
    height: 10px;
}
.statsdiv {
  font-size: 7pt;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  float: right; /* Add this */
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't do it either. What I got: i.imgur.com/vi7m6e4.png - read more link is not centered with rest of text

Answer (score 1):

You could make your div go out of the flow making its position absolute :

```
.statsdiv{
    font-size: 7pt;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    align: right;
    padding: 0 15px;
    width: 96%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Needs a little tuning to make it right in all definitions though...